# Can not set the query of ContentBySearchWebPart programatically

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, development, content-search-web-part

I have written below code to provision ContentBySearchWebPart.

```
ContentBySearchWebPart searchWebPart = new ContentBySearchWebPart();
searchWebPart.ID = "g_1ea2d77b_6b6c_4aca_b78f_3165a78884a8";
searchWebPart.Title = "Test webpart";
searchWebPart.NumberOfItems = 4;
searchWebPart.ItemTemplateId = "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Content Web Parts/Item_Picture3Lines.js";
searchWebPart.RenderTemplateId = "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Content Web Parts/Control_ListWithPaging.js";

 var QueryString = new DataProviderScriptWebPart
 {
     PropertiesJson = searchWebPart.DataProviderJSON
 };
 QueryString.Properties["QueryTemplate"] = "(IsDocument:True OR contentclass:STS_ListItem) Path:{Site.URL}";
 searchWebPart.DataProviderJSON = QueryString.PropertiesJson;
```

But it is not setting query property of the web part.

When i check the web part in edit mode and see the query , it takes the default query for the web part (Not setting the query which i am passing).

Can anyone please let me know the solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working.

I had to set the SourceID property as well as QueryTemplate property.

Please find the working code as below:

```
 var contentBySearchQueryString = new DataProviderScriptWebPart
 {
     PropertiesJson = searchWebPart.DataProviderJSON
 };

 contentBySearchQueryString.Properties["SourceID"] = "8413cd39-2156-4e00-b54d-11efd9abdb89";
 contentBySearchQueryString.Properties["QueryTemplate"] = "(IsDocument:True OR contentclass:STS_ListItem) Path:{Site.URL}";

 searchWebPart.DataProviderJSON = contentBySearchQueryString.PropertiesJson;
```

The source ID is the result source for the query which is "Local SharePoint Results".